# T-SQL Group by day date but i want show query full date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to show the date field can not group.

My Query:

```
SELECT  DAY(T1.UI_CreateDate) AS DATEDAY, SUM(1) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM mydb.dbo.LP_UseImpression T1 WHERE T1.UI_BR_BO_ID = 45  
GROUP BY DAY(T1.UI_CreateDate)
```

Result:

```
DATEDAY     TOTALCOUNT
----------- -----------
15          186
9           1
3           2
26          481
21          297
27          342
18          18
30          14
4           183
25          553
13          8
22          469
16          1
17          28
20          331
28          90
14          33
8           1
```

But i want to show the full date...

Example result:

```
DATEDAY             TOTALCOUNT
-----------         -----------
15/06/2015          186
9/06/2015           1
3/06/2015           2
26/06/2015          481
21/06/2015          297
27/06/2015          342
18/06/2015          18
30/06/2015          14
4/06/2015           183
25/06/2015          553
13/06/2015          8
22/06/2015          469
16/06/2015          1
17/06/2015          28
20/06/2015          331
28/06/2015          90
14/06/2015          33
8/06/2015           1
```

I want to see the results...
I could not get a kind of results...

How can I do?

Thanx!

Comment: Your query is taking the date field, acquiring the day-of-month from it, then grouping by that.  So all dates that are the 1st of the month are grouped together.  But you're asking that the result includes the full date?  Does that mean you don't want to group by the day-of-month, but rather want to group by the date *including* the month?  *(Such that 1st Jan and 1st Feb do not get grouped together?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just casting to `date` to remove any time component:

```
SELECT CAST(T1.UI_CreateDate as DATE) AS DATEDAY, COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM mydb.dbo.LP_UseImpression T1
WHERE T1.UI_BR_BO_ID = 45  
GROUP BY CAST(T1.UI_CreateDate as DATE)
ORDER BY DATEDAY;
```

`SUM(1)` for calculating the count *does* work.  However, because SQL has the `COUNT(*)` function, it seems a bit awkward.

Answer (score 0):

So you can group by `DAY(T1.UI_CreateDate)` or use full date for grouping. But these are different . As both these dates  `'2015-04-15'` and `'2015-12-15'` result in same `DAY` value of `15`.

Assuming you want to group on DAY rather than date please try the below version of query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
   T1.UI_CreateDate as DATEDAY,
   count(1) over (PARTITION BY DAY(T1.UI_CreateDate) )   AS TOTALCOUNT 
FROM mydb.dbo.LP_UseImpression T1 WHERE T1.UI_BR_BO_ID = 45
```

sql fiddle for demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3337/1